# How to filter two maps and make third map by using Lambda expression java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```java
Map<String,String> persons = new HashMap<>();
persons.put("aaaa@testing","123456789");
persons.put("bbbb@testing","987654321");

Map<String,UsersDTO> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("aaaa@testing", UsersDTO1);
users.put("bbbb@testing",UsersDTO2);

//Below one is the my required final map by using above two maps by using java 8 Lambdas
Map<String,UsersDTO> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
finalMap.put("123456789",UsersDTO1);
finalMap.put("987654321",UsersDTO2);
```

How to make `finalMap` by using the two maps above? This type of question might be there but I want to give special focus on this so that's why I am posting it. How to make by using the lambda expressions?

Comment: You want your final map to be `<String,String>` but then you are puting `UserDto`s to it?

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake, finally i want <String,UserDto> generic type map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that but note that you will get a `Map<String,UserDto>`:

```
Map<String,UsersDTO> finalMap =
        persons.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, e-> users.get(e.getKey())));
```

As suggested by Andreas, if the email doesn't have a match between the two maps, you could handle that case. For example by ignoring the entry :

```
Map<String, UsersDTO> finalMap =
        persons.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> users.containsKey(e.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, e -> users.get(e.getKey())));
```

Comment: You're missing a `filter()` call to exclude `persons` entries without matching `users` entry.

Comment: Indeed.But not sure how the op would handle that (filtering, default value, exception) but added anyway an example with filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like so :

```
Map<String, UsersDTO> finalMap = users.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(user -> persons.get(user.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

---

Here is a simple [ideone demo](http://www.ideone.com/8YNjDd) to the expected result.

---

As commented by Andreas, you need another filter to make sure that each entry has a matching :

```
Map<String, UsersDTO> finalMap = users.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(user -> persons.containsKey(user.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(user -> persons.get(user.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You're missing a `filter()` call to exclude `users` entries without matching `persons` entry.

Comment: @Andreas you are correct, without the filter it can cause some issues. fix it ;)

Comment: Can Please suggest where i can learn this complex lamdas, suggest me any resource for learing

Comment: @SrikanthJanapati by practice and learning books for example https://www.amazon.fr/Java-Lambdas-Pragmatic-Functional-Programming-ebook/dp/B00J3B3J3C

Comment: @YCF_L Thank you